# Best practice to set variable on subclass constructor

Tags: java

Superclass

```
public class food {
    private String name;
    public food( String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void foodName() {
        System.out.println("This is "+name);
    }
}
```

Subclass

```
public class Bacon extends food {
    private String name;
    public Bacon (String name) {
        super(name);
        this.name=name;
    }
    public void foodName() {
        System.out.println("This is a food named " +name);
    }
}
```

For the variable *name* of the subclass Bacon to work in the overriden method, is this the best practice or are there better ways to do it?

```
public Bacon(String name){
    super(name);
    this.name=name;
}
```

Comment: I have not seen it any other way.  What alternative were you thinking?

Comment: Can you not make food.name protected instead of private?

Comment: Why duplicate name field definition? why not use OOP inheritance?

Comment: @ergonaut I wasn't thinking anything. Just wanted to know if there was any other way to do it. I've got my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @EricGalluzzo Yes. I am just playing around with Java. How would making it protected help?

Answer (score 1):

In class `Bacon`, the declaration of `name` hides the declaration of name in `Food` class, and all references to name in Bacon class refer to the `Bacon.name` not `Food.name`.

So please go through the [Inheritance chapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) again.

There is no need of `name` declaration again in `Bacon class`. Remove the declaration, since it is extending Food class, it will have name property.
To access name in the child classes add access specifier to the name property as protected like

```
protected String name; //inherited classes can have access to this property
```

Also modify the constructor

```
public Bacon (String name) {
    super(name);
    // (removed) this.name=name; 
}
```

Comment: Removing `Bacon.name` will cause the `foodName()` method in `Bacon` to stop compiling since `name` is private to `food`.

Comment: Oh I didnt check that function. I'll update my answer to make it protected, so it should work fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In this case more logical will be to mark `name` variable as protected, it will allow subclasses and package members to access it.

Superclass

```
public class food {
    protected String name;
    public food( String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void foodName() {
        System.out.println("This is "+name);
    }
}
```

And remove duplicate `name` variable in subclass and just use constructor if superclass

```
public class Bacon extends food {
    public Bacon (String name) {
        super(name);
    }
    public void foodName() {
        System.out.println("This is a food named " +name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no overriding of variables in Java, and you can't access a private variable from a superclass in a subclass in general; so what you have is two separate variables called `name`.

If you want your subclass to have access to the variable then make it protected in the superclass:

```
public class food {
   protected String name;
   //...
}
```

If you really want to restrict access, and the subclass only needs to use the variable (not modify it), then you should uses a getter method.

```
public class food {
   private String name;
   protected String getName() {
      return name;
   }
   //...
}
```

You subclass can then call `getName()` instead of using `name`.